# PHP form submitting without filling out required fields such as branch

Tags: php, forms

Form submit without required fields being filled out I am new to PHP so this is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: make it not required !! most probably your java script validation failed !

Comment: You cannot assume JavaScript @zod as the PHP may be in the same file as the form.

Comment: You have to share your code with us Shane, or we cannot help.

Comment: Please see code below

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
include ("app_code/config.php");
session_start();

$errors=array();
if ($_POST){
 
$admin_url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".ADMIN_DOWNLOAD_FILEPATH;
$message="Attention Sales Staff\n<br />One of your website visitors has sent you a request for quotation.Please see the details below:\n<br />";

//$message="Attention Sales Staff\nOne of your website visitors has sent you a request for quotation. Please see the details below:\n";
//Check each field and build errors array if problems found 
 if(isset($_POST['Iagree']) && !empty($_POST['Iagree'])){
  $message .="\n\n<br />I have read and agree to the Toyota Jamaica privacy policy.";
 }
 else {
  $errors['Iagree']='Check if you read and agree to privacy policy.'; 
 }
 if(isset($_POST['model']) && !empty($_POST['model'])){
  $message .="\n<br />Please send a price quotation on this model: {$_POST['model']}\n<br />";
 }
 else {
  $errors['model']='Please enter your preferred model.'; 
 }
 
 if(isset($_POST['companyname']) && !empty($_POST['companyname'])){
  $message .="\n<br />Company Name: {$_POST['companyname']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['fnamelname']) && !empty($_POST['fnamelname'])){
  $message .="\n<br />First Name & Last Name: {$_POST['fnamelname']}";
 }
 else {
  $errors['fnamelname']='Please enter name.'; 
 }
 if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
  $email= trim($_POST['email']);
  list($userName, $mailDomain) = split("@", $email); 
  if (checkdnsrr($mailDomain, "MX")) {//check email domain address validity
   $message .= "\n<br />Email: ". $email;
  }
  else{ 
   $errors['email']='Please enter your valid email address'; 
  } 
 }
 else {
  $errors['email']='Please enter your email. ';
 } 
 
 if(isset($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['phone'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Phone: {$_POST['phone']}";
 }
 else {
  $errors['phone']='Please enter your phone number.';
 }

 if(isset($_POST['besttime']) && !empty($_POST['besttime'])){
  $message .="\n<br />Best time to call: {$_POST['besttime']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['fax']) && !empty($_POST['fax'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Fax: {$_POST['fax']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['address'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Address: {$_POST['address']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city'])){
   $message .="\n<br />City: {$_POST['city']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['zcode']) && !empty($_POST['zcode'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Code: {$_POST['zcode']}";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['pcontact']) && !empty($_POST['pcontact'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Preferred contact: {$_POST['pcontact']}";
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['paytime']) && !empty($_POST['paytime'])){
   $message .="\n<br />I plan to purchase within: {$_POST['paytime']}";
 }
  if(isset($_POST['paymethod']) && !empty($_POST['paymethod'])){
   $message .="\n<br />Payment method: {$_POST['paymethod']}";
 }
  if(isset($_POST['adoptions']) && !empty($_POST['adoptions'])){
  //$message .="\nAdditional Request(s): {$_POST['adoptions']}";
  $message .="\n<br />Additional Request(s): ".strip_tags($_POST['adoptions']);
 }
 //$message .="\n";

 $message.="\r\n\n<br /><hr /><br /><small>You can visit the admin area to download quote requests. \r\n\n<br />To login to the admin area, please visit \r\n<br />". $admin_url ."</small>"; 


 //Create variables for the email
 $to = 'sales@toyotajamaica.com';
 
 $subject = 'Toyota Jamaica Quotation Request Form';
 //$bcc = 'loraine@zipltd.com';
 //$from = 'do-not-reply@toyotajamaica.com';
 //if no errors, send email and redirect to acknowledgment page
 if (!$errors){  
  /*
  mail( $to, $subject, $message,
                "From: $email\r\n" .
    //"Reply-To: $email\r\n".
    "Bcc: $bcc\r\n".
                "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
  header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?name=$_POST[fnamelname]");
  exit();
  */
  $qr='
  insert into quote (model, companyname, fnamelname, email,phone,besttime,fax,address,city,zcode,preferredcontact, paytime, paymethod, additionaloptions )
  values ("'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['model'])).'", 
"'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['companyname'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['fnamelname'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( trim($_POST['email']))).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['phone'])).'", 
"'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['besttime'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['fax'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['address'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['city'])).'", 
"'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['zcode'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['pcontact'])).'", 
"'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['paytime'])).'", 
"'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['paymethod'])).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities( $_POST['adoptions'])).'")';
  
  //Insert record to database
     $insert = mysql_query($qr) /* or die(mysql_error())*/; 
  
  if ($insert)  { 
      
    /***** notification email to admin ***********/
    $body = "<html>\n". "<body>\n".$message. "</body>\n"."</html>\n";
    $headers  = "From: $email\r\n"."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(). 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n". 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ); 
    /***** notification EOF ***********/ 
    
    header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?name=$_POST[fnamelname]");
    exit();
  }//end insert 
  
 }//end no errors
 
}//end post
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"/>
        <title>Welcome to Toyota Jamaica | Quote Request</title>
    
        <!-- STYLE SHEETS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styletoggle.css" />
        
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
    <!-- JQuery librery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Cufon Text Replacment -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon/cufon-yui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon/quicksand.font6aec.js"></script>
    
        <!-- JQuery Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.asyncImgLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Custom javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/costum.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav_current.js"></script>

            <!--[if IE 6]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dd_belated_png.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('.pngfix');
            </script>
   <![endif]-->    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/analytics.js"></script>
    </head>    <body>
<div><a id="topArrow" class="tooltip pngfix" title="To Top" href="#top"></a></div>
<!-- start #top -->
        <?php include ('_includes/top.php') ; ?>
        <!-- end #top -->
  <!-- start #topnav -->
        <?php include ('_includes/menu_top.php') ; ?>
        <!-- end #topnav -->
        <div id="featured" class="wrapper pngfix">
            <div id="page_title" class="center">
                <h1>Request a Vehicle Quote</h1>
                <div class="title_slogan">Get a vehicle quotation from the comfort of your own home! </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end #featured -->
        <div id="main" class="wrapper">
            <div id="inner_main" class="center">
              <? include ('_includes/breadcrumbs.php');?>
                <div id="sidebar" class="right_sidebar">
                    <span class="sidebar_top"></span>
                    
                    <?php include ('_includes/menu_shopping.php') ; ?>
                    
                    <?php include ('_includes/side_promos_about.php') ; ?>
                    <span class="sidebar_bottom"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- end sidebar -->
                <div id="main_left">
                
                    <p>Complete the form below to request a quotation on a new vehicle.</p>
                    
                    <div class="hr_divider"></div>

   <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="quote">
    <?php if( count( $errors) > 0) {  ?> 
  <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; color:red;">Please correct the errors and then resubmit. </span> 
  <?php }
    else if (isset($_GET['name'])) 
    {  //if no errors exist ?> <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;color:red"> Thank You <?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> your request has been successfully sent.  <?php  }  ?></span> 
                
                <h4>Request a price on a new vehicle</h4>
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Model:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['model'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['model'];?></font><?php  }?>
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                
      <select name="model" class="input-Field_12">
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="" selected>Select a model</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Yaris" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Yaris">Yaris</option> 
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Corolla" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Corolla">Corolla</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "FT86" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="FT86">FT86</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Prius Hybrid" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Prius Hybrid">Prius Hybrid</option>            
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Camry" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Camry">Camry</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Camry Hybrid" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Camry Hybrid">Camry Hybrid</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "RAV4" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="RAV4">RAV4</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Fortuner" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Fortuner">Fortuner</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Prado" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Prado">Prado</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Land Cruiser" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Land Cruiser">Land Cruiser</option>

  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Hilux" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Hilux">Hilux</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Hiace Panel Van" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Hiace Panel Van">Hiace Panel Van</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Hiace Bus" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Hiace Bus">Hiace Bus</option>
  <option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Coaster" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Coaster">Coaster</option>
  <!--<option <?= $_POST['model'] == "Daihatsu Terios" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Daihatsu Terios">Daihatsu Terios</option>-->
   </select>
         </div>
         
         <h4>Select Branch Location</h4>
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Branches:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['branches'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['branches'];?></font><?php  }?>
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                
      <select name="branch" class="input-Field_12">
        <option <?= $_POST['branches'] == "" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="" selected>Select a branch</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['branches'] == "Spanish Town Road Branch" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Spanish Town Road Branch">Spanish Town Road Branch</option> 
        <option <?= $_POST['branches'] == "Old Hope Road Branch" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Old Hope Road Branch">Old Hope Road Branch</option>
        <option <?= $_POST['branches'] == "Montego Bay Branch" ? "selected" : "" ?> value="Montego Bay Branch">Montego Bay Branch</option>
        
   </select>
         </div>
         
           <p class="inputheader_12">Additional options:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errormesssageArea" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div id="inputTextAreaBG">
                <textarea id="messageField" name="adoptions" value="" cols="60" rows="3" style="font-size:10px"><?php if (isset($_POST['adoptions'])) echo $_POST['adoptions'] ;?></textarea>
                </div>
                
                
                 <div class="hr_divider"></div>
                <h4>Please enter your contact information</h4>               
                
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <p class="inputheader_12">Company Name:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                 <input name="companyname" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['companyname'])) echo $_POST['companyname'] ;?>" type="text" size="30" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <p class="inputheader_12">Email:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['email'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['email'];?></font><?php  }?>
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'] ;?>"  type="text" size="30" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                    
                    
                    
                <p class="inputheader_12">Phone:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['phone'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['phone'];?></font><?php  }?>
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['phone'])) echo $_POST['phone'] ;?>"  type="text" size="20" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="20">
                </div>
                
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Address:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12"> 
                <input name="address" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['address'])) echo $_POST['address'] ;?>"  type="text" size="35" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Code:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="zcode" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['zcode'])) echo $_POST['zcode'] ;?>"  type="text" size="20" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="30">
                </div>
                
                </td>
                <td width="50px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                
                    
                <p class="inputheader_12">First Name & Last Name:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['fnamelname'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['fnamelname'];?></font><?php  }?>
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="fnamelname" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['fnamelname'])) echo $_POST['fnamelname'] ;?>"  type="text" size="30" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="50">
                </div>
                
                 <p class="inputheader_12">Fax:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="fax" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['fax'])) echo $_POST['fax'] ;?>"  type="text" size="20" class="input-Field_12"  maxlength="20">
                </div>
                
                
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Best time to call:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <select name="besttime" class="input-Field_12">
      <option <?= $_POST['besttime'] == "Morning" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Morning">Morning</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['besttime'] == "Noon" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Noon">Noon</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['besttime'] == "Afternoon" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['besttime'] == "Evening" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Evening">Evening</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
                <p class="inputheader_12">City:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <input name="city" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['city'])) echo $_POST['city'] ;?>"  type="text" size="20" class="input-Field_12" maxlength="30">
                </div>
                
                
                
                <p class="inputheader_12">Preferred contact:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <select name="pcontact" class="input-Field_12">
      <option <?= $_POST['pcontact'] == "Email" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Email" >Email</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['pcontact'] == "Phone" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Phone" >Phone</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['pcontact'] == "Fax" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Fax" >Fax</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['pcontact'] == "Any" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Any" >Any</option>
        </select>
        </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                
                    
        <div class="hr_divider"></div>
        
        
        <h4>Tell us about your purchase plans</h4>
        
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        
        <p class="inputheader_12">Purchase time:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12"></p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <select name="paytime" class="input-Field_12">
      <option <?= $_POST['paytime'] == "72hours" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="72hours">I plan to purchase in the next 72 hours</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['paytime'] == "1month" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="1month">I plan to purchase in the next month</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['paytime'] == "3months" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="3months">I plan to purchase in the next 3 months</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['paytime'] == "undecided" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="undecided">I am undecided</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        
        </td>
        <td width="50px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        
         <p class="inputheader_12">Payment method:</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                </p>
                <div class="inputTextBG_12">
                <select name="paymethod" class="input-Field_12">
      <option <?= $_POST['paymethod'] == "Cash" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Cash">Cash</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['paymethod'] == "Bank Loan" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Bank Loan">Bank Loan</option>
      <option <?= $_POST['paymethod'] == "Toyota Finance" ? "selected" : "" ?>  value="Toyota Finance">Toyota Finance</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
          
        
        
       
        
        <blockquote class="blockindent">
                     <p class="asterisk">In order to submit the form, you must agree to the privacy policy. To read the privacy policy, <a href="/privacy.php" target="_blank" >click here</a></p>
      </blockquote>
      
      <p class="inputheader_12"><input type="checkbox" name="Iagree" value="Iagree" <?= $_POST['Iagree'] == "Iagree" ? "checked" : "" ?>/> I have read and agree to the privacy policy.</p>
                <p class="requireField_12">(required)</p>
                <p id="errorName" class="ErrorData_12">
                <?php if (!empty($errors['Iagree'])) {?> <font color="#FF0000"> <?php  echo '*'.$errors['Iagree'];?></font> <?php }?>
                </p>
                
                <div class="hr_divider"></div>
      
      <p id="sendButton">
       <a href="javascript: document.quote.submit();">Send</a>
      </p>
      
   </form>
      
     
     
                
                        
                    
                </div>
                <!-- end #main_left -->
            </div>
            <!-- end {#main .center} -->
            <p class="clear">
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end main -->
         <?php include ('_includes/footer.php') ; ?>
        <!-- start footer_bottom -->
        <?php include ('_includes/footer_bottom.php') ; ?>
        <!-- end footer_bottom -->
    </body>
</html>
```